# Infinite loop when entering invalid input

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and I want to check all my array elements are integer except the first element.

I wrote the following code, but the loop never stops once I insert wrong input.

```
bool validate_int(char input[]){
    fgets(input,10, stdin);
    for(int i = 1; i < strlen(input); ++i) {
        if(!isdigit(input[i])){
            i = 1;
            fgets(input,10, stdin);
        }
        else{
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You must never ignore the return value of an input operation. Your approach is broken beyond repair.

Comment: @KerrekSB Uh... Only if error checking is a requirement. I hear people say that a lot, but seriously, this is probably a tiny toy program for learning string operations, not for learning about handling I/O errors.

Comment: i just  want to check the array elements that start from index no 1 is integer not other type.

Comment: This should not be the main problem, but I think you should begin your check from `i=0`, not `i=1`.

Comment: @immibis: No, this is fundamental to systematic thinking. If an action can have two possible outcomes, you need to recognize and continue appropriately from each outcome and adjust your mental state of the world accordingly. You don't get to be sloppy about that if you ever want to be able to build anything more complex than hello world.

Comment: Or your should use `fgets(input+1,10-1,stdin);` if you want the index start from 1.

Comment: This code is confusing; do not mix validation with getting input. Separate reading input from validating input. Have a wrapper function call `validate_int()` for each line read from input, stopping only when `validate_int()` returns success. Make sure `fgets(3)` is successful.

Comment: @MikeCAT OP explicitly said he wants every position in the array but the first to be a number.

Comment: @MikeCat  . I wann save index 0 for char.  A12222, B1123 . Index 0 is suppose to be char not int

Comment: Sorry for misunserstanding.

Comment: The second `i = 1;` should be `i = 0;`. Otherwise, the first character won't be checked due to `++i`.

Comment: can you rewrite the code  MikeCAT?

Comment: @user3262564 Just change `i = 1;` in the body of the `if` to `i = 0;`.

Comment: newline isn't digit.

Comment: @cool Guy,  changing i = 0 in the body has no effect

Comment: @CoolGuy, using `< strlen()`, `input[i]` cannot be `'\0'`

Comment: @user3262564 go with Filipe's comment. You *might* get along reading new input inside the validation loop, but it's really a flawed design.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I guess you're right...

Comment: i do know what to add or remove, it seems everything i got from you guys does not work sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Your code has some small problems. Here is an better way to do it *(untested)*:

```
bool validate_int(char input[]) /* Bad function name; See @Filipe's comment */
{
    for(;;) /* Infinite loop */
    {
        if(fgets(input, 10, stdin) == NULL) /* If fgets failed */
        {
            puts("fgets failed");
            return false; 
        }

        int i, len = strlen(input); 

        if(len > 0 && input[len - 1] == '\n') /* If there is a newline character at the end of input */
            input[--len] = '\0'; /* Replace the '\n' with '\0' and decrement len */

        if(!isalpha(input[0])) /* If the first character of input is not an alphabet */
            continue; /* Loop again */

        if(len == 1) /* There is no number */
            continue;

        for(i = 1; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if(!isdigit(input[i])) /* If not a digit */
                continue; /* Loop again */
        }

        break; /* Get out of the loop */
    }

    return true;
}
```

A more better way would be to seperate input and validation into two seperate functions *(untested)*:

```
bool getInput(char input[])
{
    if(fgets(input, 10, stdin) == NULL) /* If fgets failed */
    {
        puts("fgets failed");
        return false; 
    }

    int len = strlen(input); 

    if(len > 0 && input[len - 1] == '\n') /* If there is a newline character at the end of input */
        input[--len] = '\0'; /* Replace the '\n' with '\0' and decrement len */

    return true;
}

bool validate(char input[])
{
    if(!isalpha(input[0])) /* If the first character of input is not an alphabet */
        return false;

    int i, len = strlen(input);

    if(len == 1) /* There is no number after the character */
        return false;

    for(i = 1; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if(!isdigit(input[i])) /* If not a digit */
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and in the calling function *(again, untested)*,

```
char input[10];
if(getInput(input))
{
    if(validate(input))
    {
        puts("Input is in correct format");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Input is in wrong format");
    }
}
else
{
    puts("Failed to get input");
}
```

Comment: I think you call `strlen` too many times. I think `len` should be calculated (`int len = strlen(input);`) just after calling `fgets` and checking its return value. iThe `len` should be used for checking for newline, and should be adjusted (decremented) if the newline is deleted.

Comment: Shouldn't we show the OP the good way of doing this? By separating input from validation?

Comment: @Cubia Yes. Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach I would take, which is must cleaner IMO :

This is your validation function :

```
bool customValidation(char *string) 
{
    int len = strlen(string);
    if (!isalpha(string[0]) || (len > 1 && !isdigit(string[1])))
        return false;

    for (int i = 1; i < len && string[i] != '\n'; ++i)
        if (!isdigit(string[i]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

This is how you would use it :

```
char input[10];
do
{
    fgets(input, 10, stdin);
} while (!customValidation(input));
```

Obviously you should rename customValidation() to something more significant.

Comment: @CoolGuy Been a while since I've last used fgets(), I thaught that we needed to add an extra char to accommodate the '\0'. Edited.

Comment: I think that your code does not work as expected when the input has a single digit, e.g: `A\n`

Comment: @CoolGuy Added validation so that if there isn't a digit in the first position, it'll fail.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
bool validate_int(char input[]){
    bool valid;

    do{
        valid = false;
        fgets(input,10, stdin);
        for(int i = 1; input[i] && input[i] != '\n'; ++i) {
            if(!isdigit(input[i])){
                valid = false;
                break;
            } else {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    }while(!valid);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

```
int a_Length = 10;
char input[a_Length];
fgets(input,a_Length, stdin);
for(int i = 1; i < strlen(input); ++i) {
    if(!isdigit(input[i])&& input[i]!='\n'){
        i = 0;
        printf("Again try: ");
        if (input[a_Length - 1 ]!='\n')
            getchar();
        fgets(input,10, stdin);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) The question is about C, not C++ 2) `fgets` does not leave the newline character in the standard input stream. It consumes it and stores it in `input` (assuming there is space in `input`).

Comment: Can you please run `fgets(input,10, stdin);char c= getchar();`? explain why char c = '\n' gets ??@CoolGuy

Comment: What is the input? Is it 9 characters long excluding the `\n`?

Comment: input is "c12345678" . Is there any things that user will give input with consider a newline character ? than it is okay.

Comment: here, in the problem - it says that `check all my array elements are integer except the first element.` - then if by default, it gets the newline character then the loop will not stop. `fgets take the `n` number of character, if it get early newline then stop. it doesn't mean that it will read the last newline character. fgets stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first.`

Comment: `c` is `\n` because there is no space to store it in `input` and so, `fgets` does not consume it. "_Is there any things that user will give input with consider a newline character ?_" -- Do you mean the stuff when `fgets` consumes the `\n`? If so, any input less than 9 characters long excluding the `\n` will make `fgets` store everything, including the newline character.

Comment: fgets consumes newline when it gets newline early in the line. If we consider that the user give 9 character strings excluding newline then the newline is not consume. So, then it need to handle it then.

Comment: is there any reason for downvote ? any reason can help me to learn a new things :)

Comment: What ever you said is correct, but your code, after changing `cout` to `printf`, will work as expected only when the input is 9 characters long, excluding the newline character. It doesn't work as expected when the input is less than 9 characters. Try running it.

Comment: Change the code. is it now ok? is it passing all the test cases ?@CoolGuy

Comment: Please change the `cout` to `printf` as the question is about [tag:c], not [tag:c++].